# I seem to have lost Secondary Power status, how can I earn it back?

Tags: victoria-2

I've recently started playing Victoria II as the Netherlands (home country represent, yo) and am so far doing relatively well.

However, when I tried to colonize new territories in the East Indies I was informed that only Great Powers and Secondary Powers are allowed to colonize, and I'd somehow slipped to "Civilized Nation" status while I wasn't looking.

What's the quickest way to climb back up that sociopolitical ladder? I have a thriving economy and a pretty big budget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secondary powers are countries from 9th to 16th place. To improve your status, you just need to increase your points. If you have a big budget, invest in new factories and recruit soldiers. It would waste money if compared to regular development but if you really need points, that's the easy way.

Comment: Can't invest in factories as the Liberal Party took over as the ruling faction, but the recruiting I can probably do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get prestige points is to participate in **wars**.  Unfortunately, this is also a pretty easy way to *lose* prestige points, so make sure you can actually win before you declare war.